# Buffering data in memory - Writable.final() hook never called

Tags: node.js, stream

The test program at the end of this question is supposed to buffer up data in a `PassThrough` stream object and then report how much there was once it's all buffered.  (This is cut down from a real program that is supposed to buffer up data in a `PassThrough` or `gzip` stream object, depending on settings, and then feed it to a library that wants a *readable* stream with all the data already available.)

It works correctly for small "blob"s, e.g.

```
$ node --version
v8.11.1

$ node test.js 128; echo $?
s.write called
done writing
s.write called
s.final called
s.final: 128 bytes written
run complete
42
```

But if the data passed in the `s.write` call is sufficiently large, the `final` hook doesn't get called: instead, the interpreter silently exits after calling the `write` hook twice, the way it does when it thinks there are no more tasks to run.

```
$ node wtf.js 16385; echo $?
s.write called
done writing
s.write called
0
```

(On my computer, the cut-off is exactly at 16385; 16384 or fewer bytes works correctly.  I presume that this is some internal size limit and it might not always be the same.)

The [writable.write documentation](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v8.x/docs/api/stream.html#stream_writable_write_chunk_encoding_callback) leads me to believe that a paused transform stream should be willing to buffer arbitrarily large amounts of data.  What gives?  How can I make this work reliably?  (When answering, please keep in mind that in the real program, the `PassThrough` stream may instead be a `zlib.createGzip` stream.)

```js
"use strict";

const stream  = require("stream");

let n = parseInt(process.argv[2], 10);
if (!Number.isFinite(n) || n <= 0) {
    console.error(`usage: ${process.argv[1]} nbytes`);
    process.exit(1);
}
let blob = "x".repeat(n-1);

let shim = new stream.PassThrough();
let strm = new stream.Writable({
    write(d, e, c) {
        console.log("s.write called");
        shim.write(d, e, c);
    },
    final(c)       {
        console.log("s.final called");
        shim.end();
        let buf = shim.read();
        console.log(`s.final: ${buf.length} bytes written`);
        c();
    }
});

function run(s) {
    return new Promise((res, rej) => {
        s.on("finish", res);
        s.on("error", rej);
        s.write(blob);
        s.end("\n");
        console.log("done writing");
    }).then(() => {
        console.log("run complete");
        return 42;
    }, (e) => {
        console.log("write error");
        console.error(e);
        return 19;
    });
}

run(strm).then(process.exit);
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't have a complete solution, but I've got some (big) clues which hopefully set you on your way.

Firstly, 16384 is the default [`highWaterMark`](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_constructor_new_stream_writable_options) for the buffer size used by the writable stream - this is documented. Any writes beyond that (in a non-draining stream) start returning false as a signal to the source to stop sending in data to write. Of course, the source is free to ignore this signal and continue dumping data in the stream (as you've done). As you correctly observed, Node will (and does) continue to buffer the chunks written until memory is exhausted and it crashes. But by the time you call end() if there's still undrained data in the stream's buffer, it will not end gracefully - no finish event/_final() call.

So what happens with small (aka < 16384 bytes) blobs? Your writable stream is able to drain completely to the passThrough (which itself never drains, but that's another story). So it calls _final(), emits finish and ends gracefully.

With > 16384 byte blobs, the passThrough's own highWaterMark is breached after the first write of 16384 bytes. While this write does drain as far as the outer writableStream is concerned, the next write of "\n" from the end() doesn't. So the writableStream is still having data in buffer when you `end()` it and it has to force-close. No finish, no _final call.

Some interesting experiments you can try (one at a time):

a) Increase the highWaterMark of the passThrough. Set it to > 16384 and you should be able to push more data into the writableStream.

b) Don't pass the callback argument `c` you got in writableStream's _write() directly to shim.write(), instead call the callback yourself after calling shim.write().

```
shim.write(d,e);
c();
```

This will signal to writableStream that you're always draining it regardless of whether your target actually consumes the data or not. Ugly, but it works.

c) Remove the "\n" from end()